# Using git submodule to import a python project

Tags: python

(I realise there are a lot of questions on StackOverflow relating to python relative imports; I suspect also that I'm doing this all wrong; but here goes anyway ..)

I have a python project (mysubmod) organised as follows:

```
/__init__.py
/lib
- /__init__py
- /foobar.py
/models
- /__init__.py
- /hello.py
```

Importantly:

- /models/hello.py imports lib.foobar
- /models/hello.py has a **main** block which runs some tests

I then have a second project (myproj) into which I've imported mysubmod as a git submodule; myproj is now organised as follows -

```
/mysubmod
/scripts
- /__init__.py
- /__test.py
```

Where:

- scripts/test.py imports mysubmod.models.hello

However when I run /scripts/test.py from the command line, the interpreter now complains that mysubmod/models/hello.py can no longer find lib.foobar.

Reload.

Changed mysubmod/models/hello.py so it now imports ..lib.foobar

Now I can run /scripts/test.py without complaint, but I can no longer run any of the submod scripts as files from the command line; I can only run them as modulles using the python -m option.

Also I can no longer run the submod project files on a standalone basis, even with the -m option, as the interpreter complains about 'Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package'; I have to go up a directory level, ie can only really run mysubmod from the myproj root (where it has mysubmod as the root level directory).

This all seems pretty unsatisfactory. I want to be able to:

- use git submodule to import mysubmod into myproj so that it 'just works'
- continue to be able to develop mysubmod on a standalone basis (ie run scripts as files not modules)

Does anyone have any views on how to do this ? Any views on best practices with respect to git submodule and python ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK the answer is (after many wrong turns)

- add a single top level package mysubmod (eg 'helloworld')
- with mysubmod imported into myprod as a submodule, symbolically link the helloworld package into the myprod root ('ln -s mysubmod/helloworld helloworld')

This way, the package structure is maintained whether you are working with the submod as a submodule or on a standalone basis.

Answer (score 6):

You could also add `mysubmod` to `sys.path` when you starting your `myproj`. Then `mysubmod/models/hello.py` will find `lib.foobar`.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a somewhat nicer solution. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29747054/477453) provides an example.

Comment: Where to add the `sys.path.append("myproject/mysubmod")`? I tried to add it into `myproject/scripts/some_script.py`, but the submodule still reported the broken imports problem when I executed `some_script.py`