# How to import python file from git submodule

Tags: python, git-submodules, python-import

I've a project which uses git submodules. In my python file I want to use functions from another python file in the submodule project.

In order to work I had to add the **init**.py file to all subfolders in the path. My folder tree is the following:

```
myproj
├── gitmodules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── mygitsubmodule
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       └── file.py
└── myfile.py
```

Is there any way to make it work without touching mygitsubmodule ?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can add to `sys.path` in the file you want to be able to access the module, something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/me/myproj/gitmodules")
import mygitsubmodule
```

This example is adding a path as a raw string to make it clear what's happening. You should really use the more sophisticated, system independent methods described below to determine and assemble the path.

Also, I have found it better, when I used this method, to use `sys.path.insert(1, ..` as some functionality seems to rely of `sys.path[0]` being the starting directory of the program.

Comment: I was hopping a less trickier way (editing the sys.path just for an import..), but I guess that it may not be possible to do it in another way :)

Comment: @pedrorijo91: `sys.path` is the Python load path, not to be confused with the `$PATH` environment variable or it's equivalents. It's quite lightweight to add to, and doesn't alter your environment.


**Edit:** I would suggest working out the path at runtime instead of hard-coding it. Something involving the current path (`os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`) and `os.path.join`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73885828/1291935 for how to do this for the entire package at once.

Answer (score 19):

I am used to avoiding modifying *sys.path*.

The problem is, when using *git submodule*, submodule is a project directory, not a Python package. There is a "gap" between **your module** and **that package**, so you can't import.

Suppose you have created a submodule named *foo_project*, and there is a *foo* package inside.

```
.
├── foo_project
│   ├── README.rst
│   └── foo
│       └── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

My solution will be creating a **soft link** to expose that package to your module:

```
ln -s foo_project/foo foo
```

```
.
├── foo_project
│   ├── README.rst
│   └── foo
│       └── __init__.py
├── foo -> foo_project/foo
└── main.py
```

Now you can import *foo* in the *main.py*.

Comment: That might work, if the imported file doesn't depend on other files within foo_project. It unfortunately fails, if there are json files loaded or other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

For reference,

```
       from submodulefolder.file import func_name
```

or

```
       import submodulefolder.file as lib_name
```

where `file` excludes the extension of `file.py`, seems to work in relative terms without modifying the subfolder / git submodule with a [**init**.py since python 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3),
as shown [here](https://blog.finxter.com/python-how-to-import-modules-from-another-folder/).

Tested on py3.8.5 linux native and py3.7.8 anaconda Windows, both in Spyder's Ipython-console, as well as natively on linux via [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio).