# Importing from a git sub-module (ImportError)

Tags: python, git-submodules, python-import

I get an `ImportError` when I am importing from a sub-module in the way I thought One Was Supposed To Do It.

I have the following package:

```
pkg/
  __init__.py
  cow.py
  pizza.py
  pkg.py
  components/
    components.py
    otherstuff.py
    __init__.py
```

cow.py:

```
print "Hello"
from components import foodle
```

components.py:

```
foodle=5
```

and the `__init__`'s are empty.

I am having trouble putting things in the right place or organizing them properly.  When, from the pkg directory, I try

```
from pkg import foodle
```

I get "ImportError: cannot import name foodle"

What is the right way to arrange files and import from submodules?  I have read [How to import python file from git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746958/how-to-import-python-file-from-git-submodule) ;  I have tried messing with `sys.path` in `components/__init__.py` and in `cow.py`, to no avail.
This package is shared on git, so it needs to be portable. `components` is actually a git sub-module.

Putting `from components import *` in the `__init__py` in components/ seems to work, but I thought usually that file stays empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements I was missing are (these are my interpretation, may still be incorrect):

- If it's a package (with `__init__.py`), use it from outside the `pkg` folder, not from inside.  ie, using a package both ways (calling from outside and using modules from within) might be hard to set up, so don't. This is the main insight that solves my problem.
- the dot notation for getting submodules and subpackages works both for files and for folders within `pkg`.  Thus, from some other folder, but with `pkg` in my path, I can call any of the following:

  ```
  import pkg
  from pkg.cow import foodle
  from pkg.components import foodle
  from pkg.components.components import foodle
  ```