# Import submodule with missing __init__

Tags: python, git, python-2.7

I used the following command to add an existing project as submodule to my project.

```
git submodule add https://github.com/...
```

However, the submodule root does not contain an `__init__.py` file. Is it possible to import the features from this submodule without making changes to it?

Contents of .gitmodules:

```
[submodule "name"]
path = name
url = https://github.com/name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution is to add your submodule to your project, and than add a symbolic link into the actual package next to the submodule (or where ever it makes sense to put it)

So you'll have

```
project
  - submodule
    - package
    - setup.py
  - my_awesome_script.py
  - package (symbolic link to submodule/package)
```

then you can just import it through the symbolic link.

```
import package

package.work_your_magic()
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15676423/5784822

Answer (score -1):

You simply have to grab the content of the submodule:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

This will checkout all the content of the submodules into your working directory under the submodule folder.

---

> However, the submodule root does not contain an **init**.py file. Is it possible to import the features from this submodule without making changes to it?

### **Yep**

In this case you will have to use `subtree` instead of submodules. The main difference between subtree and submodule is that subtree content is managed at the root level so you will be able to use checkout command to checkout any content from any path in your project while in submodules you cant, and you will need to copy it.

Comment: That part I understand, but it solves nothing. Its common for projects to have a setup.py in the root directory and the actual source in a subdirectory.

Comment: Ok i got you now, updating the answer accordingly.